# Ghost not working on CentOs 7 despite clean install

Tags: linux, centos7, ghost-blog

I followed most of [this tutorial](https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fpoloch.fr%2Finstaller-ghost-avec-nginx-sur-centos-7%2F) to install Ghost on CentOs 7 but, despite the install going perfectly I am unable to see the welcome page.

Here are a list of commands I used, let me know if I made a mistake somewhere.

```
$ yum -y update
$ yum -y install gcc-c++ openssl-devel 
$ cd /usr/local/src && wget -O node-latest.tar.gz http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz 
$ tar -xzf node-latest.tar.gz 
$ cd node-v* # example:  cd node-v0.10.33/
./configure
make && make install
cp /usr/local/bin/node /usr/bin/node
cp /usr/local/bin/npm  /usr/bin/npm
mkdir  -p /var/www/ && cd /var/www/
curl -L -O https://ghost.org/zip/ghost-latest.zip
unzip -d ghost ghost-latest.zip
cd ghost
useradd ghost
chown -R ghost:ghost /var/www/ghost/
npm install --production
npm start --production
```

At this point I can see the success message, and that ghost is installed

```
> ghost@0.5.6 start /var/www/ghost
> node index

Migrations: Up to date at version 003
Ghost is running...
Your blog is now available on http://my-ghost-blog.com
Ctrl+C to shut down
```

But, I went to localhost:2368 and 127.0.0.1:2368 but nothing shows up. just an browser 404 error.

I thought this might be a port issue so, I tried to open a port

```
firewall-cmd --zone=dmz --add-port=2368/tcp
```

tried permanent, reload ... still nothing.

Comment: Did you do the nginx step?

Comment: @NathanC No I didn't. Shouldn't Ghost run by itself, Node as the web server?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ghost, but typically when following a tutorial you do all the steps ...I'm assuming nginx does some magic to make the node.js server work.

Comment: To my understanding Nginx just re-routes port :2368 to :80, maybe it adds some bonus in performance, because [nodejs + ghost](http://www.howtoinstallghost.com/how-to-install-ghost-on-centos-server-6-4/) is by itself a webpage & a server.

Comment: Any sort of logging that it does that you could look at? A 404 means you're actually hitting the server, but something in the configuration isn't working correctly.

Comment: No, its not a server 404, just a browser 404. I don't know what to call a browser error. It is as if search for a domain that does not exist.

Comment: Check that your process is actually listening on the port you expect by running `ss -lnp` as root.

Comment: Yes, I have checked it is listening. that is actually one of the first things I did